# python importing module, find out what is exactly wrong

Tags: python, import

I try to import a module.

```
# coding: utf-8
import rb

def main():
  print "working"

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

if "import" directive is present, program prints nothing
 and I get:

[image]

Echo $? shows that program worked correctly. 
How can one check whether module was correctly loaded?

P.S. It seems that this module is present in the directory, 
 
because if I delete all another files except interpreted script, I get:

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems like rb.py calls `os._exit(0)`.

Comment: it's a good idea to check it! it's rb.py file -  http://paste.debian.net/30379/  .  I didn't find such instruction there(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete this line from rb.py:

```
sys.stdout = _rbdebugfile(sys.stdout.fileno())
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `rb.py` file, there is a funny line at the end : `sys.stdout = _rbdebugfile(sys.stdout.fileno())`, this will redirect the standard stdout (where the printed characters go) to a special file instead of the console.

The lost characters are in the file created by rb.py.